# When to use componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle method?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new to React/Redux and have a problem with state.

**TrajectContainer.jsx**

```
class TrajectContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            trajects: props.trajects,
            onClick: props.onClick
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        console.log('componentWillReceiveProps', nextProps);
        this.setState(nextProps);
    }

    render() {
        // When the componentWillReceiveProps is not present, the this.state will hold the old state
        console.log('rerender', this.state);
        return (<div className="col-md-6">
            <h2>Trajects</h2>
            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.state.onClick}>Add new Traject</button>
            {this.state.trajects.map(traject => <Traject traject={traject} key={traject.name}/>)}
        </div>)
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = function (store) {
    console.log('mapToStateProps', store);
    return {
        trajects: store.trajects
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = function (dispatch, ownProps) {
    return {
        onClick: function () {
            dispatch(addTraject());
        }
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TrajectContainer);
```

When a reducer returns a new state, the component will rerender with the new data.

However: if I remove the componentWillReceiveProps function, the render() function has the old state.

I checked the data received in mapStateToProps, and this is new New State.
So I don't understand why I need the componentWillReceiveProps function in order for the render function to receive the new data.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You don't need `state` to handle those changes. `trajects` belongs to both `state` and `props` (coming from redux's `connect`). Also, setting state on every `componentWillReceiveProps` is not a good practice. 

I'd remove `trajects` from state and work only with incoming props. They will change whenever necessary and you'll always have the up-to-date values.

Comment: @HemersonCarlin That is what I want yes, but the state in render() is not the up-to-date state passed from mapStateToProps, that is my issue. I only get the new state when I used .setState which is why I made this StackOverflow Q!

Comment: Try to remove the state and use `this.props.trajects` instead.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`componentWillReceiveProps` is required if you want to update the state values with new props values, this method will get called whenever any change happens to props values.

---

> In your case why you need this componentWillReceiveProps method?

Because you are storing the props values in state variable, and using it like this:

`this.state.KeyName`

That's why you need `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method to update the state value with new props value, only props values of component will get updated but **automatically state will not get updated**. If you do not update the state then `this.state` will always have the initial data.

`componentWillReceiveProps` will be not required if you do not store the props values in state and directly use:

`this.props.keyName`

Now react will always use updated props values inside render method, and if any change happen to props, it will re-render the component with new props.

As per **[DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)**:

> componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component
>   receives new props. If you need to update the state in response to
>   prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare this.props
>   and nextProps and perform state transitions using this.setState() in
>   this method.
>
> React doesn't call componentWillReceiveProps with initial props during
>   mounting. It only calls this method if some of component's props may
>   update.

**Suggestion:**

Do not store the props values in state, directly use `this.props` and create the ui components.

Comment: This is a great answer! Yet, anyone seeing this should be aware that as of now, the method "componentWillReceiveProps()" has been deprecated. You should use, "componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)". See here for further explanation: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Answer (score 20):

## Update

`componentDidUpdate()`

should now be used rather than componentWillReceiveProps

also see an [article from gaearon](https://overreacted.io/writing-resilient-components/) re writing resilient components

There are two potential issues here

1. Don't reassign your props to state that is what you are using redux for pulling the values from the store and returning them as props to your component

Avoiding state means you no longer need your constructor or life-cycle methods. So your component can be written as a stateless functional component there are performance benefits to writing your component in this way.

2. You do not need to wrap your action in dispatch is you are passing mapDispatcahToProps. If an object is passed, each function inside it is assumed to be a action creator. An object with the same function names, but with every action creator wrapped into a dispatch will be returned

Below is a code snippet that removes the state from your component and relies on the state that has been returned from the redux store

```js
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const TrajectContainer = ({ trajects, addTraject }) => (
 <div className="col-md-6">
  <h2>Trajects</h2>
  <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={addTraject}>Add new Traject</button>
  {trajects.map(traject => <Traject traject={traject} key={traject.name} />)}
 </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = ({ trajects }) => ({ trajects });

export default connect( mapStateToProps, { addTraject })(TrajectContainer);
```

Answer (score 10):

In your case you will require `componentWillReceiveProps` and you have to update the state when you receive new props. Because

- In your constructor, you have declared your state as below. As you can see you construct your `state` using the props that are passed in. (This is why you require `componentWillReceiveProps` and the logic to update it there)

  ```
  this.state = {
      trajects: props.trajects,
      onClick: props.onClick
  };
  ```
- So when your props, changes `componentWillReceiveProps` is the function that gets called. The constructor does not gets called. So you have to set the state again so that the changes goes into the state of the component.
- However your logic should be as below. With a condition so that you can prevent repeated state updates if its called multiple times.

  ```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   console.log('componentWillReceiveProps', nextProps);
   if (this.props !== nextProps) {
    this.setState(nextProps);
   }
  }
  ```

One should store the props into state, only if you are going to modify the content of it. But in your case i see that there is no modification. So you can directly use `this.props.trajects` directly instead of storing it into the state and then using it. This way you can get rid of the `componentWillReceiveProps`
So your render function will use something like below

```
{this.props.trajects.map(traject => //what ever is your code.... }
```

Comment: Thanks Panther, your explanation is really clear! I do plan on extending the component and allow modification of certain props so I will use your example!

Comment: this.props !== nextProps will always return true

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue add `withRouter()` like this:

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TrajectContainer));
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your implementation is that you are duplicating your Redux store state (comming from the props) into your React state (this.state)

In your example, if `store.trajects` is updated, then `this.props.traject` will be updated and a render will be triggered only if `this.props.traject` is used in your render method (not the case).

Since you are using the state instead of the prop in your render method, you have to manually change the state of you component using `this.setState` to trigger a render.

This is not a good pattern: I would advise not to use the state, and use directly the props like this:

```
class TrajectContainer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<div className="col-md-6">
            <h2>Trajects</h2>
            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.props.onClick}>Add new Traject</button>
        {this.props.trajects.map(traject => <Traject traject={traject} key={traject.name}/>)}
    </div>)
}
}
const mapStateToProps = function (store) {
  console.log('mapToStateProps', store);
  return {
    trajects: store.trajects
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = function (dispatch, ownProps) {
   return {
      onClick: function () {
        dispatch(addTraject());
      }
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TrajectContainer)
```