# React child component not re rendering when prop is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing a simple todo-app where I tried to render an *EditComponent* based on the *id* of the note clicked so that I could populate the existing details in the edit note form.
I am storing the active note id in ***Parent's state***.
For the first time when *EditComponent* is rendered, it works as expected.
However, when I change the *id* using *setState*, the existing render is not getting updated with new note details.
This is the function which gets executed when a particular note's edit button is clicked

```
  setEditState = id => {
    this.setState({id,isEdit:true})
  }
```

Here's my Parent render()

```
render() {
    let form;
    if(this.state.isEdit){
      form = <EditComponent id={this.state.id} />
    }
    else{
      form = <AddComponent />
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ViewComponent notes={this.state.notes} setEditState={this.setEditState} deleteNote={this.deleteNote} />
        {form}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Here's where I'm populating the *EditComponent* state.

```
    async componentDidMount(){
        const note = await this.getNote(this.props.id)
        console.log(note.data.subject)
        this.setState({
            id:this.props.id,
            modifiedSubject: note.data.subject,
            modifiedNote: note.data.noteText
        })
    }
```

This is one of the inputs in edit form in child render()

```
<input className="form-control" type="text" onChange={this.handleSubject} value={this.state.modifiedSubject} />
```

My hunch:
Am I not getting it updated again and again because I'm using *componentDidMount()*? If so, is there any lifecycle method which executes when the prop passed to child changes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `componentDidMount` is only called the first time the component is rendered. If you need to react to prop changes, have a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: Please attach the rest of EditComponent and parent component

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()`  for it.

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113044/when-to-use-componentwillreceiveprops-lifecycle-method)

Comment: That method was renamed to `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps` and is deprecated. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating